# How to execute sudo command in org-babel in relative path under current working directory

Tags: org-babel, tramp, sudo

I want to execute sudo command in org-babel like this:

```org
#+begin_src shell :dir "/sudo::" :cache no
make
sudo make install
#+end_src
```

It works fine. It use TRAMP /sudo: method.

But I need to execute sudo command relative under current working directory. As following
block shows:

```org
#+begin_src shell :dir "/sudo::data/code/quirc" :cache no
make
sudo make install
#+end_src
```

But it does not work. It is under `/root` instead of current working directory.
So how can I execute sudo command under a specific directory as in org-babel
like upper?

EDIT:
Might add an advice to change TRAMP sudo method default directory to babel src block's directory? Don't know how to change this in TRAMP code. Have not found any `tramp-default-directory` related variables.

Comment: Have you tried with a trailing slash at the end of a path?

Comment: With a trailing slash like `"/sudo::data/code/quirc/"` does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suddenly come up with string concat idea.

Here is the very simple solution.

```
#+begin_src sh :dir (concat "/sudo::" (expand-file-name "data/code"))
pwd
#+end_src

#+RESULTS[(2020-07-20 10:34:50) b20fc4ca99ae523b3497adaa26b8945c57b06254]:
: /home/stardiviner/Org/Wiki/Computer Technology/Programming/Emacs/Data/Emacs Packages/Org Mode/data/code
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine above. It's cleaner not requiring a local variable. It seems that keeping the current directory should be the default behavior.

Comment: I original indeed have this idea. But I found it's not a good idea. I digged the ob-core.el source code, it's not good to keep current default directory for remote path like tramp method path. For example `:dir /ssh:user@host:data/code` Like this remote path should not keep default directory. There is a complex solution, add a new header argument or emacs defcustom option to control this behavior. But it's not trivial. So currently my solution should be the simpiest and elegant now.

Answer (score 8):

You must use an absolute local directory path. Like this:

```
#+begin_src shell :dir "/sudo::/data/code/quirc" :cache no
make
sudo make install
#+end_src
```

See the leading slash in `/data/code/quirc`.

Edit: You must recompute the directory for the root shell. Something like this:

```
#+begin_src shell :dir "/sudo::" :var dir=(expand-file-name "data/code/quirc") :cache no
cd $dir
make
make install
#+end_src
```

Comment: What I want to execute under a relative path not absolute path. As my question described.

Comment: `/sudo::data/code/quirc` means a relative directory under the home dir of user `root`. And this is `/root`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I need to relative directory under current working directory.

Comment: You mean the relative directory under current working directory, but with sudo?

Comment: yes. that what I need.

Comment: @stardiviner I'm in the same boat with you. I hope my following solution would be good enough for your needs.